# Python Syntax for Chained Conditionals

Tags: python, conditional-operator

I'm a beginner in Python currently self-learning via the book "How to Think like a Computer Scientist"
From an exercise from the book on Chained Conditionals, Syntax taught was:

```
 def function(x,y)
   if ..:
      print ".."
   elif..:
      print ".."
   else:
      print".."
```

However, when I tried this to find out if its legal, it worked:

```
 def function (x,y)
   if ..:
     print ".."
   if ..:
     print ".."
```

Is the latter a correct syntax? Or is it not even considered a chained conditional?
I would like to find out that even if this is legal in Python, is it a "good way" to write     the code?

All kind help is sincerely appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that code executed? because after every `def` you need to have an ":" for example: `def function(x,y):`

Comment: let's say your function is determining "what clothes you wear" and the if statements are "if raining => wear a raincoat" and "if sunny => wear shorts" ... In the first example, you would either wear a raincoat OR shorts, but in the second example, as Michael points out, you might do BOTH, ie wear a raincoat AND shorts .. Does that help ?

Comment: hi PsychicOak, you pointed out correctly. I did miss out the colons. Hi Richard, yes it does help :). I see that now, thank you :)

Answer (score 13):

Though your second example is working, it is *not* the same thing as the first example.  In the second, every `if` condition will be evaluated, regardless of whether or not a previous one was true and executed.  In the chained `if/elif` example, the whole thing is treated as a unit and only the first matched condition will be executed.

#### For example:

```
# An if/elif chain
a = 2
b = 3

if a == 2:
  print "a is 2"
elif b == 3:
  print "b is 3"
else:
  print "whatever"

# prints only
"a is 2"
# even though the b condition is also true.
```

#### However

```
# Sequential if statements, not chained
a = 2
b = 3

if a == 2:
  print "a is 2"

if b == 3:
  print "b is 3"

# prints both
"a is 2"
"b is 3"
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This illustration is very simple and clear for someone like me to understand. Appreciate it :)

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't call the second variant a chained conditional. It's just a sequence of (possibly unrelated) `if` statements.

The main difference is that the first variant always executes exactly one `print` statement, whereas in the second variant multiple `print` statements could get executed.